# 2-dim Dictionary, key as a string

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, key

I have a possibly simple Question but I haven't found a solution, yet.
I am trying to acces a 2-dim dictionary with the help of a string varialbe, but cannot access it correctly. It is really important that i can save the key in a string variable in the context of my code

A quick example:

```
x = {"one":{"one":1},"two":2}
s1 = "two"
x[s1]                                                                                                                                      
2                                                                                                                                              
s2 = '["one"]["one"]'                                                                                                                                            
x[s2]
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                             
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                          
KeyError: '["one"]["one"]'
```

Is there anyway to store this 2-dim key to a variable, to access the dictionary later?

Comment: Why is it  *really important that i can save the key in a **string** variable in the context of my code*. This is very bad practice, saving each key in a tuple of keys would be better, can you do that instead?

Comment: The answer is *no*. To access a nested dictionary you *need* more than a key. You can make your dictionary flat or use more than a key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way would use a `tuple` of keys instead of a string like that eg.

```
>>> # from functools import reduce (uncomment in Py3)
>>> x = {"one":{"one":1},"two":2}
>>> def access(d, keys):
        return reduce(dict.get, keys, d)


>>> access(x, ("two", ))
2
>>> access(x, ("one", "one"))
1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for seems like a terrible idea. Why must the strings be as you say? If you aren't interested in the intermediate dictionary - just use the whole string as the key

```
>>> x = {'["one"]["one"]':1,"two":2}
>>> s1 = "two"
>>> x[s1]                                                                                                                                      
2
>>> 2                                                                                                                                              
2
>>> s2 = '["one"]["one"]'                                                                                                                                            
>>> x[s2]
1
```

Comment: Thanks for the really quick replies.Thanks for the really quick replies. I will try to explain my problem a bit more in detail.

This dictionary i need to access contains constantly updated information. I did not code this by myself but i need to work with it for a project. And this dictionary hast this "nested" structure.